# Kibana not saving dev tools history across sessions

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, search-guard

I have Kibana plugin installed in each ES node. Kibana is behind nginx reverse proxy because it's served from `/kibana/` route. Elastic is protected with SearchGuard plugin.

Question: **History for dev tools/console is reset with each login (after each login, history is empty)**. Now, I'm not sure if I'm missing something or that's expected behaviour when SearchGuard is in use? I remember that worked well before installing SearchGuard. Not sure if it's coincidence or it's indeed related. It's saving properly during one session.

Elastic version: 6.1.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in local storage under sense:editor_state in Chrome.

If it's wiped out daily or the cache is cleared, so will your searches be.

use ?load_from= in your url and save your queries in a json file... be aware of CORS if you use a web app of your own.

Comment: Can you please explain this part with `?load_from`?

Comment: in the url, you can use load_from to specify an http path to a JSON file containing queries. Example: http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console?load_from=https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/snippets/tutorial-load-dataset/1.json